# Wait value in bootstrap confirm modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

The question seems stupid, but I can't figure out how to wait the confirmation button for return a value. Javascript is based on single thread so I need to know how can I set something like a callback function until a button pression, this is the structure of the dialog:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirmation" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <label>Are you sure?</label>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-ok" data-dismiss="modal">Continue</button>
                <a class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button id="go">press me</button>
```

and js:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#go').click(function()
    {
        $('#confirmation').modal('show');
        //if the user has pressed the .btn-ok button then an alert appear
        alert(true);
    })
});
```

In practice when the user press the button a bootstrap dialog appear, I need to display an alert only if the user press the Continue button `.bnt-ok`, but actually I can't understood how to do this. Someone could show me how? Thanks.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/29022/)

**UPDATE**

1 User fire an event and function `one` is executed:

```
one: function()
{
    if(two()) //if function two return true then show alert
    {
        alert(true);
    }
}
```

2 The function two show the bootstrap dialog:

```
 two: function()
 {
    $('#confirmation').show();

   //here I need to check if the user has pressed btn-ok, if yes,
   //I need to return true, otherwise false

   return true;
 }
```

3 The problem's come in the function `two`, 'cause there is no way to stop the function until the user button click. So the confirmation dialog is displayed but the function return true. How can I wait the user click?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply, attach a click handler to the `.btn-ok` element.

As such:

```
$('.btn-ok').click(function(){
   alert(true);
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/29023/)

EDIT:

Check out solution to your problem using ES6 promises.

```
const modal = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
       $('#confirmation').modal('show');
       $('#confirmation .btn-ok').click(function(){
           resolve("user clicked");
       });
       $('#confirmation .btn-danger').click(function(){
           reject("user clicked cancel");
       });
      }).then(function(val){
        //val is your returned value. argument called with resolve.
        alert(val);
      }).catch(function(err){
        //user clicked cancel
        console.log("user clicked cancel", err)
      });
```

[Updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/29049/). Note, that it is using [ES6 promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), and you should check browser support or transpile your code (using babel for example).

Comment: the question is more complicated, your solution is a workaround, 'cause imagine that instead of the button that execute the activity there is a function that display the bootstrap dialog, all is different

Comment: @AgainMe not sure what you mean

Comment: Let me explain better, so my bootstrap dialog are displayed by a function called by a button pressure. Now this function return a value, but I need to stop the function before that it returns a value 'cause when the bootstrap dialog is displayed I need to wait the user choice, and after this return the value from a function that allow me to perform task in another method. I don't if is more clear, if not I can make an example for you.

Comment: @AgainMe javascript is async language, all is based on events and callbacks, there are some ways to make it look synchronous though like promises. Are you willing to use ES6?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133899/discussion-between-againme-and-adam-wolski).

Comment: uhm is not possible without ES6?

Comment: @AgainMe not in a way you want, since all of these are synchronous, and bootstrap modal does not allow to pass callbacks. (You can create an abstraction for it though)

Comment: Could you please add a solution pure js?

Answer (score -3):

I understand this problem well.
Pure Typescript solution looks like this:

```
const result: boolean = confirm(message);
                if (result == true) {
                    return ConfirmationResult.ConfirmationResultPositive;
                } else {
                    return ConfirmationResult.ConfirmationResultNegative;
                }
```

where ConfirmationResult.ConfirmationResultPositive is some enum.
The deal is confirm function shows standard js window and **waits** the user result (blocks further execution). Unfortunately bootstrap does not have this **standard** functionality. For example, WinForms, WPF and UMP (clear async) has the same standard behaviour.
I also suppose that with Promise<> we can workaround it with bootstrap modal.