# Show Bootstrap Modal before proceeding

Tags: javascript, jquery, async-await, bootstrap-modal

So I'm having an issue with the code in JS continuing before showing my Bootstrap Modal.

This site will prompt the user to enter information and after all the information is entered, the user hits a Save button which executes a function "passTimeToSpring()".

When this button is pressed, I want the Modal to show so the user doesn't think the site just froze, but the issue I'm having is the code proceeds first before showing the Modal. I assume this is because the Modal (upon call) executes asynchronously on a different thread?

I first noticed this happening when I had the following code running:

Modal Code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="pleaseWaitModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Please Wait...</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>The information is currently being processed. Please Wait :)</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
function passTimeToSpring() {
    $('#pleaseWaitModal').modal({show: true});
    alert(true);
    
    /* data collection stuff and POST */
}
```

Save Button HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-tooltip="" type="button" title="Fill all days before saving." onclick="passTimeToSpring()">Save All Time Entries</button>
```

When I noticed the alert showed before the Modal did, that's when I realized it would probably be an async problem, however, I'm new to JS async stuff. I found this solution [Wait value in bootstrap confirm modal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41815905/wait-value-in-bootstrap-confirm-modal), which lead me to try this code

```
const modal = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    $('#pleaseWaitModal').modal({show: true});
    resolve(true);
  }).then(function(val){
    //val is your returned value. argument called with resolve.
    alert(val);
  }).catch(function(err){
    //failure
  });

var test = await modal;
```

this still didn't seem to work.
Please help? :) thank you

Comment: `$('#pleaseWaitModal').modal({show: true});` does not delay next line execution until the modal has been shown. Which means `alert(val)` (which, in your case is `alert(true)`) will run immediately, before the modal has been rendered. Whatever it is that makes the user *"think the site just froze"* probably has to be be run `async` and the modal should be hidden when it resolves. So far you have only showed us a flawed attempt at solving a problem, not the problem itself. Therefore your chance at being provided with a solution to the actual problem is, technically, `null`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd argue relying on a modal to disable user interaction with a page is, in most cases, a mistake.

The proper solution is to handle the "locked" state independently and treat showing/hiding the *"please wait..."* modal as an optional feature of the locking function. A good implementation of such a function should allow locking/unlocking with or without showing the "please wait" modal.

Here is the simplified principle:

```
let pageLocked = false;

function toggleLockedState(state) {
  pageLocked  = state;

  // a basic example would look like this:
  $('body').toggleClass('isLocked', state);
  $('#pleaseWaitModal').modal(state ? 'show' : 'hide' );
}

function pageLockingFunction() {
  // lock page
  toggleLockedState(true);
  $.get( "your/get/url/here", function( data ) {
    // do something with data
    console.log(data);
    // unlock page
    toggleLockedState(false);
  });
}
```

An advantage of this approach is that any other function can query the current value of `pageLocked` and, when necessary, exit or enter the locked state. Also, the above is oversimplified. In a real life application state management should be handled by a specialized module/class which also exposes methods to listen and react to state changes.

Getting back to the example, a basic way of locking/unlocking a page would be to add/remove a class to `<body>` element   (`isLocked` above), applying `pointer-events: none` to all elements in the page - thus disabling interactions.

Besides handling page locking, your function displays/hides the loading modal, explaining users what's going on (why the page is locked).

Ideally, the modal should also present a "cancel loading" button which should exit the locked state so they could, for example, try again if anything went wrong. Don't forget to set `pointer-events: all` on the cancel button, so the user can interact with it, even when the page is in locked state.

---

If you want to do something with the data after it has loaded, return the call itself from `pageLockingFunction` and return the `data` inside the returned call:

```
function pageLockingFunction() {
  toggleLockedState(true);
  return $.get( "your/get/url/here", function( data ) {
    toggleLockedState(false);
    return data;
  });
}
```

and use it like this:

```
pageLockingFunction().then(data => {
  console.log('closing #pleaseWaitModal...');
  console.log(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my original post, I was attempting to push the code to show Modal on a separate thread and continue the hard work in the main thread. I decided to handle the event that was actually causing the hold up in a Web Worker (Seperate Thread).

This program uses a Java Spring back end, so the data I collect gets posted to spring, which in turn inserts the information into a Database. It's this process that causes the hold-up, as no response is returned to the browser until the insert command is completed.

After this command is completed, the page is then navigated to as GET, because refresh would just POST again.

Here's is my final code samples

timeSubmissionWorker:

```
onmessage = function(e) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "/url", false);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    xhr.addEventListener("loadend", function (e) {
        console.log(e);
        postMessage({result: true});
    });
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(e.data));
};
```

main html file:

```
function passTimeToSpring() {
    $('#pleaseWaitModal').modal({show: true});
    
    var myWorker = new Worker("timeSubmissionWorker.js");
    myWorker.postMessage(*data*);

    myWorker.onmessage = function(e) {
        //reloads the page after the information has posted.
        window.location.href = "/url";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your function "passTimeToSping()" must be declare to "() => passTimeToSpring()" for the HTML not execute before click

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-tooltip="" type="button" title="Fill all days before saving." onclick="() => passTimeToSpring">Save All Time Entries</button>
```